# Oracle - Coordinate extraction from vertices (first, last and all vertices)

Tags: sql, oracle, function, spatial

For a given feature (line or area) and for all of its members I need to extract the coordinates of (1) ***all*** the vertices, (2) ***the first*** vertex and (3) ***the last*** vertex (**3 separate queries** to create **3 different sets of results**)

I'm using Oracle spatial.

I’ve tested this sql code for the table ARAMAL (it's a 3d line entity; Primary key column: IPID; geometry column: GEOMETRY) and it works well.

- (1) - List ***all the*** vertices

  SELECT A.IPID, t.X, t.Y, t.Z, t.id FROM ARAMAL A, 
  TABLE(SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES(A.GEOMETRY)) t ORDER BY A.IPID, t.id;

Result (example for IPID=1479723):

IPID         X              Y     Z      id

1479723    -99340.38408    -102364.3603    10      1

1479723    -99341.21035    -102366.2701    11      2

1479723    -99342.03375    -102368.1783    12      3

1479723    -99342.86238    -102370.0875    13      4

...     ...             ....            ...     ...

- (2) - List ***the first*** vertex

  SELECT A.IPID, t.X, t.Y, t.Z, t.id FROM ARAMAL A, 
  TABLE(SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES(A.GEOMETRY)) t where t.id=1 ORDER BY A.IPID;

Result (example for IPID=1479723)

IPID      X                  Y    Z   id

1479723 -99340.38408    -102364.3603    10  1

- (3) How can I obtain ***the last vertex*** purely with sql (no additional functions)?

(Expected) Result (example for IPID=1479723)

IPID      X                  Y    Z   id

1479723 -99342.86238    -102370.0875    13  4

I guess this process could run faster if I use specific functions - I would also like to be able to use them.

I’ve come across a great site (Simon Greener) with some functions that I guess could do the trick

http://spatialdbadvisor.com/oracle_spatial_tips_tricks/322/st_vertexn-extracting-a-specific-point-from-any-geometry

The functions are:

***ST_StartPoint***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION ST_StartPoint(p_geom IN mdsys.sdo_geometry)
    RETURN mdsys.sdo_geometry
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN ST_PointN(p_geom,1);
  END ST_StartPoint;
/
```

***ST_EndPoint***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION ST_EndPoint(p_geom IN mdsys.sdo_geometry)
    RETURN mdsys.sdo_geometry
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN ST_PointN(p_geom,-1);
  END ST_EndPoint;
/
```

I’m a newbie to this world and I don’t really get the syntax of these functions…

- For the table ARAMAL that I’ve used before how should I use/apply them to get the results (and in the format) I need?

IPID        X                  Y    Z   id

1479723 -99340.38408    -102364.3603    10  1

....

Thanks in advance,
Best regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you are working with spatial data, you are interested in row which has maximum `id` for given `ipid`, so you can run it like here:

```
select * 
  from (
    select a.ipid, t.x, t.y, t.z, t.id,
           max(t.id) over (partition by a.ipid) mx_id
      from aramal a, table(sdo_util.getvertices(a.geometry)) t)
  where id = mx_id;
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d175ab113812a153b93b1895caa9fe28)</sup>**

There are several ways to get last row, you can use `row_number()`, subquery, like in many `top-n` questions on this site.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ponder. Much Appreciated